# Where do I go to get details on setting up different instruments?

Tags: electrochemistry

Say I want to set up a system to preform cyclic voltammetry. How do I know what instruments to get/ electrochemical cells/ etc? Is there a resource for other setups as well, like EIS?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad and hard to answer without pointing out multiple books on the topic. Here is a good one to start: [Lab Techniques in Electroanalytical Chemistry, Edited By P. Kissinger and W. Heineman](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824794451)

However, your specific experiment will depend on the type of your sample and what information you are looking for. The best place to start is to look for papers in your field and read their experimental sections.

Instrument manufacturers also write application notes specifically for this reason. You may find useful information on their websites as well. Here is an example : [Application Notes Regarding EIS from Gamry](http://www.gamry.com/application-notes/EIS/)

Full disclosure: I used to work for Gamry Instruments.